# Fixing the node positions in the layout using gephi toolkit

Tags: gephi

I am trying to create a FruchtermanReingold layout using gephi toolkit. I observed that node positions are getting changed for the same data. How to fix the node positions ? Because the layout shouldn't change if the data is same.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

There is this method `node.getNodeData().setFixed(true);` but I haven't tried it. Very recently one of my colleagues who was trying to implement a spigot couldn't get it to work

Comment: my question was to fixing the nodes using toolkit not by using the UI

Comment: yes.. you are correct..  i also tried that.. if we fix the node position we can't run force layouts